# Count the number of occurances of values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
df = data.frame(c("2012","2012","2012","2013"),
                c("tuesday","tuesday","friday","thursday"),
                c("AAA","BBB","AAA","AAA"))
colnames(df) = c("year","day","type")
```

I want to show the number of occurances (absolute frequency) of `type` values (AAA, BBB) per year and day.
Currently I wrote the following code, but it requires that I add one more dimension to `aes`, e.g. `aes(type, some_dimension, fill = as.factor(year))`. So, how can I add something like `count(type)`?

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(type, fill = as.factor(year)), 
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~day)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `geom_bar` change `stat` from `"identity"` to `"count"`, like here:

```
library("ggplot2")

ggplot(df) +
    geom_bar(aes(x = type, fill = as.factor(year)), 
             position = "dodge", stat = "count") + 
    facet_wrap(~day)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get the error `Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.` on my real data. What does it mean and how to tackle it?

Comment: You probably added `y` to `aes` part (maybe not exactly, but as a second argument). Could you show your data and code? It would be easier then.